# lex/yacc simple Q

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

Can lex and yacc be used for making a programming language? and any recommendation for some books.

some references ?

So far i have found some like :

[Build code with lex and yacc, Part 1: Introduction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lexyac/index.html)

Comment: Sure, just like `if` and `else` can be used to make an operating system.

Comment: Highly suggest you spend some time with a standard compiler book before you start down this course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly use lex and yacc to build a compiler/translator for a programming or scripting language.  There are GNU variants of these tools, called [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/index.html).  John Levine's **lex & yacc** was for many years the gold standard for books about these tools.  That book may be out of print, but I expect that the successor book, [Flex & Bison,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155972) is just as good.  To dig deeper into building a compiler, start with Aho et al., [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811), 2/e.  (Again, my recommendation is based on the first edition of this book.)